# Problem in proof of: Show that inverse of 'a' modulo 'm' exist if 'a' and 'm' are relative primes and 'm'>1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

From K Rosen's Discrete Maths,

**Theorem:** If a and m are relatively prime integers and m > 1, then an inverse of a modulo m exists. Furthermore, this inverse is unique modulo m. (That is, there is a unique positive integer a less than m that is an inverse of a modulo m and every other inverse of a modulo m is congruent to a modulo m.)

**Proof:** 
By Theorem 6 of Section 4.3, 

because gcd(a, m) = 1, there are integers s and t such that
**sa + tm = 1. 
This implies that,
sa + tm ≡ 1 (mod m).**

Because t m ≡ 0 (mod m), it follows that
sa ≡ 1 (mod m).
Consequently, s is an inverse of a modulo m.

I am struggling a lot and have gone through theorems given in the chapter multiple times, I'm unable to figure out how we can say,

**sa + tm = 1. 
This implies that,
sa + tm ≡ 1 (mod m).**

I realise that this a rookie question but if you can give me some link or even a theorem no. that would be of great help.

Comment: Cause $$sa+tm=1 \equiv 1 \pmod m$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $sa+tm=1$, then $sa+tm$ and $1$ are the same number.  Thus, they will have the same remainder when divided by $m$, which is precisely what we mean  when we say $sa + tm \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

Answer (score 0):

$sa + tm = 1 = 0 \cdot m + 1$

See? It is one greater than a multiple of $m$.